# Wrong method signature when creating web service in Axis2 in JAVA

Tags: java, methods, apache-axis, signature

Trying to generate my first Axis2 web service using eclipse.

Basically, I started creating Dynamic Web Project and having simple TestService class with one public method Echo that receives string parameter and returns it.

I used wizard to create service out of this TestService class and that seems to work with no problem. When I run Tomcat I can see my service with Echo method available.

The problem starts when I try to build client. I created another java project and called it TestClient.

Then I selected my TestService.java and selected New > Web Services > Web Service Client. For webservice client I selected my TestClient project and as expected I got two new files in my TestClient project. One of them is TestServiceStub.java.

So, the problem....

Stub generated has wrong parameter. When I try to call my Echo method from client, intellisense shows that method's signature is something like Echo(Echo Echo0)... My Echo method should be something like Echo(String string).

**Where is this parameter coming from? What am I missing?**

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

Well, figured my problem. I was missguided by some bad internet post and didn't look further than that. Everything was ok with my service, I simply didn't know how to call it properly. Here is the code that properly calls (from client) my service described above:

```
package testserviceclient;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
import testpackage.TestClassStub;
import testpackage.TestClassStub.Echo;
import testpackage.TestClassStub.EchoResponse;

public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
           TestClassStub stub = new TestClassStub();
            Echo e = new Echo();
            e.setValue("Hello World");
            EchoResponse res = stub.echo(e);
            System.out.println("Result : " + res.get_return());
        } catch(AxisFault e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... I figured the solution. I was misguided by some bad example posted on the internet. Actually everything is fine and I just didn't know how to properly called the service.